# the barcodes i created with JAVA FOR LOOP can't seem to put every image in MS Word

Tags: java, for-loop, ms-word

**i can't seem to put every image of the barcodes that i created in the MS Word it only puts the last generated barcode** i dont know what to do i tried a lot of things but doesnt work. see my images. any help would be appreciated.

Here are the images :

[image]

[image]

Here are the codes :

```
import com.aspose.barcode.BarCodeBuilder;
import com.aspose.barcode.Symbology;
import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder; 

   JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create Barcode");
            btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    String strBaseFolder = "C:\\users\\ronjonathan\\desktop\\barcode\\";
                    String query = "Select MAX(ProductID) from tblindividualproduct";
                    try

                    {

                        // Generate barcode image
                        BarCodeBuilder builder = new BarCodeBuilder();
                        builder.setSymbologyType(Symbology.Code128);
                        pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
                        rs=pst.executeQuery();
                        if(rs.next()){
                        int MAX = rs.getInt(1);
                        for(int i = 1;i <= Integer.parseInt(txtBarcode.getText()); i++){

                        builder.setCodeText(Integer.toString(i+MAX));
                        String strBarCodeImageSave = ""+(i+MAX)+".jpg";
                        builder.save(strBaseFolder + strBarCodeImageSave);

                        // Add the image to a Word doc
                        Document doc = new Document();
                        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
                        docBuilder.insertImage(strBaseFolder + strBarCodeImageSave);
                        String strWordFile = "doc.doc";
                        doc.save(strBaseFolder + strWordFile);
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");
                        }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem. i just removed the doc and docbuilder in the for loop and moved it to the upper part because if i didnt remove it. it just overwrites the document over and over again.

```
String strBaseFolder = "C:\\users\\ronjonathan\\desktop\\barcode\\";
            String query = "Select MAX(ProductID) from tblindividualproduct";
            String strBarCodeImageSave = null;

            try

            {
                Document doc = new Document();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);


                // Generate barcode image
                BarCodeBuilder builder = new BarCodeBuilder();
                builder.setSymbologyType(Symbology.Code128);

                pst=con.prepareStatement(query);    
                rs=pst.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    int MAX = rs.getInt(1);
                for(int i = 1;i <= Integer.parseInt(txtBarcode.getText()); i++){

                builder.setCodeText(Integer.toString(i+MAX));
                strBarCodeImageSave = +(i+MAX)+".jpg";
                builder.save(strBaseFolder + strBarCodeImageSave);


                docBuilder.insertImage(strBaseFolder + strBarCodeImageSave);
                String strWordFile = "doc.doc";
                doc.save(strBaseFolder + strWordFile);
                }
             // Add the image to a Word doc 

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");
```